# How to check if an entered answer is correct with HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, button

I'm developing an escape room game for my students in Google Sites, and I have a problem with de HTML code.
The goal is to enter a text answer in a text box and then check whether that answer is correct or not. If not correct, a message should appear warning this and the continue button should not be enabled; while in case the answer was correct, a message should appear congratulating them and unlock the button to continue.

I made a first version of the HTML code (see below) but it doesn't work for me, as I have problems in the if section.

Could someone please help me solve this? I am a science teacher, a novice in programming and due to COVID-19 I would like to implement something different for my students.
Thank you very much in advance!

````
<head>
<title></title>


<script>
function checkAnswers(){
    Student_answer = document.f1.Student_answer.value
    Teacher_answer = "abc"

    if (Student_answer.length == 0 || Teacher_answer.length == 0) {
        alert("You must enter an answer to continue...");
        return false;
        }

    if (Student_answer == Teacher_answer) {
        alert("CONGRATULATIONS! Your answer is correct! You have advanced to the next level");
        //<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';">Next Riddle</button>
        //NOTE: here is where the button should be activated and click on it to advance to an hyperlink 
        }

        else 
        {
        alert("Worng answer, please, keep trying...<br />");
        //NOTE: here the button must be disabled
        }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Write here your answer...</h3>
<br>

<form action="" name="f1">
Youy answer: <input type="password" name="clave1" size="20">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Check" onClick="checkAnswers()">

</form>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Give id to your input field . Use document.getElementById("your_id").value . It should work for you .

Comment: `Student_answer = document.getElementsByName("clave1")[0].value;`

Comment: Check this : 

<input id="test" type="text">
<input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Submit">

<script>
function check(){
console.log(document.getElementById("test").value);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    function checkAnswers(){
        // The following is what I changed.
        Student_answer = document.querySelector('[name="clave1"]').value
        Teacher_answer = "abc"

        if (Student_answer.length === 0 || Teacher_answer.length === 0) {
            alert("You must enter an answer to continue...");
            return false;
        }

        if (Student_answer === Teacher_answer) {
            alert("CONGRATULATIONS! Your answer is correct! You have advanced to the next level.");
            document.body.innerHTML += '<button onclick="window.location.href = \'https://www.google.com\';">Next Riddle</button>'
            //NOTE: here is where the button should be activated and click on it to advance to an hyperlink 
        } else {
            alert("Wrong answer, please, keep trying...");
            //NOTE: here the button must be disabled
        }

    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3>Write here your answer...</h3>
    <br>

    <form action="" name="f1" onsubmit >
      Your answer: <input type="password" name="clave1" size="20">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Check" onClick="checkAnswers()">

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also made some grammar and style fixes in your code.

Edit: I added the button functionality you asked about in your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect!
But when I try to put the button link in the correct answer with this code, It doesn´t work.
It is this line: 
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';">Next Riddle</button>

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @MartínPiña You need to program the JS to add the button to your HTML I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: Yes! You are a genius! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you just have a small issue in your HTML, while reading input with JS
Considering this HTML

```
<h3>Write here your answer...</h3>
<br>
<form name="f1">
  Your answer: <input type="password" name="studentAnswer" size="20">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Check" onClick="checkAnswers()">

</form>
```

I've edited the `name` of the input, as you need to "select" it from JS using the name. So as you can see the input name is now `studentAnswer`, and that's how you reference it in your JS code, which I've edited as following

```
function checkAnswers() {
// document.$formName.$inputName
  Student_answer = document.f1.studentAnswer.value
  Teacher_answer = "abc"

  if (Student_answer.length == 0 || Teacher_answer.length == 0) {
    alert("You must enter an answer to continue...");
    return false;
  }

  if (Student_answer == Teacher_answer) {
    alert("CONGRATULATIONS! Your answer is correct! You have advanced to the next level");
    //<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';">Next Riddle</button>
    //NOTE: here is where the button should be activated and click on it to advance to an hyperlink 
  } else {
    alert("Worng answer, please, keep trying...<br />");
    //NOTE: here the button must be disabled
  }

}
```

I've kept it simple to avoid confusing you, great idea you had imho

Answer (score 1):

Change,

`Student_answer = document.f1.Student_answer.value`

**to**

`Student_answer = document.getElementsByName('clave1')[0].value`

You can use [**getElementsByName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) and get element via name attribute and can get the value..

```js
function checkAnswers(){
    Student_answer = document.getElementsByName('clave1')[0].value
    Teacher_answer = "abc";
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
    if (Student_answer.length == 0 || Teacher_answer.length == 0) {
        alert("You must enter an answer to continue...");
        return false;
        }

    if (Student_answer == Teacher_answer) {
        alert("CONGRATULATIONS! Your answer is correct! You have advanced to the next level");
      form.innerHTML += 
        `<button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';">Next Riddle</button>`
        //NOTE: here is where the button should be activated and click on it to advance to an hyperlink 
        }

        else 
        {
        alert("Worng answer, please, keep trying...<br />");
        //NOTE: here the button must be disabled
        }

}
```

```html
<h3>Write here your answer...</h3>
<br>

<form action="" name="f1">
Youy answer: <input type="password" name="clave1" size="20">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Check" onClick="checkAnswers()">
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now it works better but I can not activate the link...
When I activate this code in the correct answer it doesn´t work: 
        <button onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';">Next Riddle</button>

Do you know how to put a button link in this part?

Comment: @MartínPiña You need to program the JS to create the button in the webpage. I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: @MartínPiña, Do you want to update the button inside form or to document body??

Comment: @MartínPiña, I have updated the code now and it is good practice to declare variable name starting with small letter..

Comment: That´s great! May I ask you another question? This code works perfectly, but when you touch the "Next Riddle" button the link you put there doens´t open, it says this error: "The page www.google.com has rejected the connection."
I tried with different links but all says the same.
Do you know how to solve this? It will be great that the link opens in a new tab...
Thank you very much!

Comment: @MartínPiña, Kindly check whether this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/GRpeMON resolves your issue.. You need to use ```<button onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com');">Next Riddle</button>``` to open in new tab..

Comment: Hello Maniraj! Thank you very much for you reply! May I ask you a last question? If I need to open the window in the same tab, how can a write this code?
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com');">Next Riddle</button>
Thank you very much!
Best regards,
Martin.

Comment: @MartínPiña, Could you try like ```window.open('https://www.google.com','_self')``` ??